# OpenLdap on ubuntu 16.04 :- mdb_substring_candidates: not indexed

Tags: ldap, openldap

i want to use ldap directory as phone book in ip phone
i've OpenLDAP standalone server running on my local

> configured it command

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

> added entry using ldapadd and with following content.ldif

dn: cn=max,dc=testldap,dc=com

objectClass: person

sn: steel

telephoneNumber:7896660777

description:'somedescription'

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=testldap,dc=com -w 123456 -f content.ldif
```

> when i fired ldapsearch i got results so my data is inserted correctly in directory

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost -x -D "cn=admin,dc=testldap,dc=com" -w 123456 -b "cn=max,dc=testldap,dc=com"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=max,dc=testldap,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# max, testldap.com
dn: cn=max,dc=testldap,dc=com
objectClass: person
sn: steel
telephoneNumber: 7896660777
description: 'somedescription'
cn: max

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

> **now when i configured ldap in Ip Phone and searched for the ldap contacts i'm getting following error,went through many forms and docs but not able to find how can i add indexing for this attributes**

when search telephoneNumber

> <= mdb_substring_candidates: (telephoneNumber) not indexed

when search for name

> <= mdb_substring_candidates: (cn) not indexed

Comment: Did you see this? http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/apa/indeces.html

Comment: Yes i checked that link but it didn't solved my problem!

Comment: Did you stop openldap, and run slapindex on your database?

Comment: Yes i did @user188737 that to reindex entries but somehow it didn't worked!
is there any difference between adding database index entries directly and adding it by ldapmodify? (i.e. index telephoneNumber pres,eq)

Comment: Did you do something like `index telephonenumber pres,eq,approx,sub` ? It seems that it is only complaining about substring search, so you should include sub.

Comment: yes i will do that but i don't think 'sub' is responsible for the not indexed 'error'!